# How to map domain to subdirectory?

Tags: iis, rewrite

This is for IIS6 or IIS7. I want to map a domain to a subdirectory.

For example:

http://www.example.com/dir1/test.aspx

I want to strip out the "http://www.example.com" part and redirect to a relative url, like "proj1/example/dir1/test.aspx". If that won't work, then replace with "http://www.example2.com/proj1/example/dir1/test.aspx. The user's url display must not change.

I know this has been done a million times but I've never worked on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two concepts.  One is a redirect (client-side) and the other a rewrite (server-side).

A redirect can redirect from one domain to another.  But a rewrite must be within the same site.  It can't cross domains.

Well, actually you do have an option for cross-domains.  That's a reverse proxy like ARR (IIS7 only).

[Here's a post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx) on how to rewrite to a different path while retaining the URL in IIS7.

In IIS6 you'll need to use a tool like ISAPI Rewrite [www.isapirewrite.com](http://www.isapirewrite.com).

Comment: I used the web.config sample from the post you referred to, edited it for my domains, and it immediately solved the problem.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear.